# Remove cells that do not contain partial string? error

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a long list of file paths and names in an excel column. I am working on a code to remove every cell that does not contain any partial strings that I have put in an array. I get an error "delete method of range class failed". I am very new to VBA so any tips are appreciated, here's what i've got so far:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim dontDelete As Variant
Dim sKeep As String, x As Long
Dim rngSearch As Range, c As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

dontDelete = Array("abel", "varo")

     For x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
         For j = LBound(dontDelete) To UBound(dontDelete)
             Set c = Range("A" & x).Cells
             If InStr(c.Value, dontDelete(j)) = 0 Then
                 c.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
             End If
         Next j
     Next x

End Sub
```

I believe it is the "c.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp" that is causing the problem but i don't know why?

Comment: Step through the code, as the statement looks ok, it may be the action its doing thats nota allowed, see what x is etc....

Comment: stepping through, it highlights yellow from dontDelete = Array.... down to c.Delete Shift .... where it won't go any further! is there a problem with how i have defined x and c?

Comment: 1. the code works for me 2. I don't think it does what you want it to do. This way, only cells containing both "abel" AND "varo" won't get deleted.

Comment: Interesting! Do you know 1) why I would get the error, delete method of range class failed? and also how I could modify it so that things not containing abel or varo are deleted?

Comment: do you have any filtering in your sheet? try turning every filter off

Comment: Ok, It wouldn't run because the macro I created to populate the list printed with an order and also printed the list as hyperlinks to destinations. This just leaves the problem of how do I make it so abel OR varo are not removed instead of abel AND varo???

Comment: or would it just be best to repeat the loop once for abel and once for varo?

Comment: instead of directly deleting, you could use a boolean that is set to true if one of the array contents is contained in the cell. Afterwards only delete if the boolean is false. I can post some code as an answer if you want

Comment: That would be really helpful, Thanks EngJon! Would I be right in thinking I would have to create a function as Boolean which would then take out the cells? or can it be integrated into the sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that only deletes cells if none of the strings in the array are contained instead of deleting every cell that does not contain all of them:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim dontDelete As Variant
    Dim sKeep As String, x As Long
    Dim rngSearch As Range, c As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    dontDelete = Array("abel", "varo")
    Dim deleteCell As Boolean
         For x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
             Set c = Range("A" & x).Cells
             deleteCell = True
             For j = LBound(dontDelete) To UBound(dontDelete)
                 If InStr(c.Value, dontDelete(j)) Then
                     deleteCell = False
                 End If
             Next j
             If deleteCell Then c.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
         Next x
End Sub
```

This does not solve the error, but the error wasn't caused by the code itself, so it was solved in another way.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help EngJon! Learnt some good things about Boolean types in the process too! many thanks